# How can I implement a local search algorithm in a model created on CPLEX ILOG?

Tags: optimization, cplex

I'm currently working on a large scale timetabling problem from my university. I'm using CPLEX to create the model and solve it, but due to it's size and processing time, I'm considering trying out a local search algorithm like G.A to solve it, but I'm lost on how to properly do it. Is there a way of applying a local search on it without having to reformulate the whole model?

Answer (score 1):

one possible manner to tackle your problem is to use the [CPLEX callbacks](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/OverviewAPIs/topics/Callbacks.html).

You may implement a [heuristic callback](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9UKU_12.6.0/com.ibm.cplex.zos.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex_HeuristicCallbackI.html). In this callback, you can implement your GA within the CPLEX model and use it to find a feasible solution (which I think is very difficult in various timetabling problems) or to improve your current solution.